# How to configure a service class to use BazingaGeocoderBundle with Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, service, geocoding

I am working on an application built using Symfony 3.4. I have the following service class (myproject/src/AppBundle/Utils/OutletScraper.php):

```
<?php 
// src/AppBundle/Utils/OutletScraper.php
namespace AppBundle\Utils;

use Goutte\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;

class OutletScraper
{
    private $url;
    public $outlets;
    public $abnormalFormatOutlets;

    public function __construct($url = null)
    {
        $this->url                      = $url;
        $this->outlets                  = [];
        $this->abnormalFormatOutlets    = [];
    }

    private function geocodeAddress()
    {

    }
}
```

I have a few other methods in this class which I've omitted. The config for this service class is in (myproject/src/app/config/services.yml) as follows:

```
AppBundle\Utils\OutletScraper:
    public: false
```

I am able to use the service without any problems (I've implemented it in a command).

I am now working on implementing geocoding functionality in the application. I have installed the [BazingaGeocoderBundle](https://github.com/geocoder-php/BazingaGeocoderBundle/), I'm having difficulty in understanding how to integrate this in my service class (OutletScraper.php) so that I can geocode addresses. I believe I've installed the bundle correctly, as I'm able to use the command: `php bin/console geocoder:geocode` to successfully geocode addresses.

As per the bundle documentation, I added the following to my myproject/src/app/config/config.yml file:

```
bazinga_geocoder:
    providers:
        acme:
            factory: Bazinga\GeocoderBundle\ProviderFactory\GoogleMapsFactory
            options:
                api_key: 'myapikey'
```

I understand that I should be able to call the GoogleMapsProvider from the service container but my service class (OutletScraper) does not have access to the service container. Should be specifying it as an argument in the OutletScraper config?

Appreciate if anyone can help me understand this topic better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should be specifying it as an argument in the OutletScraper config?

Yes, but also you will have to add it to the constructor as argument.

So your class should look something like this:

```
use Geocoder\Provider\Provider;

class OutletScraper
{
    private $url;
    private $geocodingProvider;
    public $outlets;
    public $abnormalFormatOutlets;

    public function __construct(Provider $geocodingProvider, $url = null)
    {
        $this->geocodingProvider        = $geocodingProvider;
        $this->url                      = $url;
        $this->outlets                  = [];
        $this->abnormalFormatOutlets    = [];
    }

    private function geocodeAddress()
    {
         $this->geocodingProvider->geocodeQuery(...);
    }
}
```

Then your config will probably look something like this:

```
AppBundle\Utils\OutletScraper:
    public: false
    arguments:
        $geocodingProvider: '@bazinga_geocoder'
        $url: ~ # represents null (also default), but can be replaced with any url string
```

I don't know that the URL is for, but when this changes a lot you might either have to create multiple services for each url or pass it later to a public method. This might not be an issue, but sometimes it is hard to see which part of a service is not really part of the service definition, leading to convoluted workarounds, that's why I'm bringing this up. If this is the ip of the geocoding service you might not even need this at all, as this is already defined in the provider you are getting from the service container.

Another problem your service has is the 2 public properties `$outlets` and `$abnormalFormatOutlets`. Your service will keep those values in between calls, which might lead to issues when you call a method and it reuses the previous values without you wanting it. What you can do is make sure that each OutletScraper inject somewhere will get a new instance, in other words the service is no longer shared by adding `shared: false` to your service configuration. Probably even better: move those variables inside the method scope, to make sure each call overwrites them.

So in order to better use Dependency Injection your class could look something like this:

```
use Geocoder\Provider\Provider;

class OutletScraper
{
    private $url;
    private $geocodingProvider;

    public function __construct(Provider $geocodingProvider)
    {
        $this->geocodingProvider = $geocodingProvider;
    }

    private function geocodeAddress($url = null)
    {
         $outlets = [];
         $abnormalFormatOutlets = [];

         $this->geocodingProvider->geocodeQuery(...);
         ...
    }
}
```

The public properties will not be stored in the class between method calls, reducing the probability of stale data producing wrong results. The service no longer depends on the url, requiring to create multiple instances for each url it is used with. Whether any of those changes is necessary depends a bit on your implementation, so make these changes with caution.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply. Sorry if this sounds silly but when I create a new object of my service class I need to pass in an instance of the Provider right?

Comment: If you want to create the new instance manually, i.e. `new ...`, then yes. Otherwise you can just inject it in the constructor of any of your services and use the configuration to pass in your scraper by referencing the `@App\Utils\OutletScraper` service id. If you make your service public, you can fetch it from the container. This is discouraged and probably why you explicitly marked it as private. If this was not intentional, keep in mind that you should only have ContainerAware controllers and even that is a "relic" and shifts more and more towards "proper" Dependency Injection.

Comment: This might seem like a lot of work, but the general idea is, that you will never have to create your services by hand and only inject them. This way, whenever the constructor changes, e.g. you add another service like in my example above, you only have to update the configuration and then every service using your service will work just like before. If you create new instances in your code, you have to go over and find all the `new` and make the changes for the new argument, which can be annoying.